# Problem with Jetpack Compose Modifier.imePadding on Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, xiaomi

IME not working on Xiaomi devices correctyly(scrolling sometimes to half input or hide all, soometimes look good). I not see any reasone why an how a i can fix them. Flow is very easy if i press a input field animation attach this field to keyboard. On phones other than Xiaomi (tested on xiamomi mi11 and xiami 11 t pro) evrything look like good.  [LINK TO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfgIx.png)

My code :
I   set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in my AndroidManifest.xml file and call WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) in my app
and also :

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(SinsayAppTheme.colors.smoke)
        .imePadding()
```

Any idea why this not working on xiaomi devices correctly. Or any other idea to to this ?

compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha07'

Answer (score 0):

**Result**
Problem it was with miui 12.5+. My solution was scroll to this "edit text" before keyboard get focus and right now working this same as other devices .